# Proving statement about power sets using fact that Z = X ∩ Y

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The statement I'm trying to prove is

If Z = X ∩ Y , then P(Z) = P(X) ∩ P(Y).

My proof is as follows:

Let $U\in P(Z)$ so $U\subset Z$ and since Z = X ∩ Y, then $U\subset (X\cap Y)$.
Hence $U\subset X$ and $U\subset Y$. Then, $U\in P(X)$ and $U\in P(Y)$ so $U\in (P(X)\cap P(Y))$. Therefore $P(Z)\subset (P(X)\cap P(Y))$.
$\\$

Then I'm not sure whether to do the same line of working but backwards to show that $(P(X)\cap P(Y))\subset P(Z)$ which would then I'm assuming prove that P(Z) = P(X) ∩ P(Y). I don't know if this is a valid method though, as it would be the same working as above except the other way round.

Hoping my reasoning is better here, my last question had a very obvious error in it :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be valid, and the backwards direction would look very similar because some of your statements could actually be if and only ifs (pretty much every step uses a definition). Here's a modified version of what you wrote:

$U \in P(X \cap Y) \iff U \subseteq X \cap Y \iff U \subseteq X$ and $U \subseteq Y \iff U \in P(X)$ and $U \in P(Y) \iff U \in P(X)\cap P(Y)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see you've used iff in between everything so does that mean you wouldn't even need to do it in the backwards direction?

Comment: Yes, because by transitivity, you get that an element is in $P(X \cap Y)$ if and only if it is in $P(X)\cap P(Y)$, so they have exactly the same elements.